# Can’t get Search results by full Title value

Tags: search, title, property, managed

Please, help me with understanding SP Search logic.

I have some list. The “Title” field in this list can have values like “iso 8841271.050-2017”, “sto 89-11.05-17”, “lt 8841271.082-2019”.

I created custom SharePoint Advanced Search Web Part and added property restrictions “Title”. I enabled "Complete Matching" for Title managed property.

Now I can find documents by full Title only, for example "sto 7702.002-2009". I haven't search results if I try to find by Title contains "7702.002" or "7702*".
Without "Complete Matching" I have opposite problem. In this case, Search doesn’t return results if I try to find document by full title "sto 7702.002-2009".

For example, if I try to find by “sto 7702.002-2009” title value the search returns no results. But if I search for “7702” value, I can see the documents with part “7702” in Title.
About Title managed property parameters:

1. Type: text
2. Search Ability: yes
3. Queryable: yes
4. Possibility of extraction: yes
5. Allow multiple values: yes
6. Refinement Support: no
7. Ability to sort: no
8. Safe for anonymous users: no
9. Nickname: no
10. Marker Normalization: no
11. "Complete Matching":  no

I would like to get results by parameters “sto 7702.002-2009”, “7702.002-2009” and “7702”. 
Would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The issues you are facing are known issues. There are limitations on how the **Keyword Query Language (KQL)** works. [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference?redirectedfrom=MSDN) is the documentation for the same. Please go through this for complete understanding of how to search and how to write queries.

Comment: And if the request doesn't include special characters, for example request Title contains "030".

http://My Site.com/My page.aspx?k=Title:"030"

The Search Results return documents with “Title” contains “030” and document with “Title” contains “it 40/276/30-6-1” (for example) and it is not right too. Which managed property parameters influence this behaviour?

Comment: I found this strange Search behaviour.

I try to find documents with title "sto kpp 8841271.uit.5.09.43-2019"

I get no results. The URL after request looks like 

http://MY SITE/SitePages/Results.aspx?k=DocTitleISM%3A"sto kpp 8841271.uit.5.09.43-2019"

When I deleted ' " ' in URL:

http://MY SITE/SitePages/Results.aspx?k=DocTitleISM%3Asto kpp 8841271.uit.5.09.43-2019

it works fine. How can I send request without " ?